# Join two tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables

**studentdemo:**

```
sid |   date        |   status
--------------------------------
10  |   2013-12-28  |   1
11  |   2013-12-28  |   1
12  |   2013-12-28  |   1
13  |   2013-12-28  |   1
10  |   2013-12-30  |   1
11  |   2013-12-30  |   1
12  |   2013-12-30  |   1
13  |   2013-12-30  |   1
```

**spdemo:**

```
    date    |   status
------------------------    
2013-12-28  |   cd
2013-12-29  |   wd
2013-12-30  |   cd
```

Using the query

```
SELECT *
FROM `studentdemo`
  RIGHT JOIN spdemo
    ON spdemo.date = studentdemo.date
WHERE spdemo.date BETWEEN "2013-12-28"
    AND "2013-12-30"
```

results in null values for the date `2013-12-29`:

```
NULL NULL NULL 2013-12-29 WD
```

Is it possible to get an output with sid?

```
sid |   date        |   status  |   date        |   status
-------------------------------------------------------
10  |   null        |   null    |   2013-12-29  |   wd
11  |   null        |   null    |   2013-12-29  |   wd
12  |   null        |   null    |   2013-12-29  |   wd
13  |   null        |   null    |   2013-12-29  |   wd
```

Comment: Since there are no `sid`s for the 29'th, what `sid`s should show up? All used for any other date?

Comment: can you please edit to change table1 and table2 to the appropriate spdemo/studentdemo ?

Comment: Are you using the right join type? Are you sure you don't want a left join or a inner join, or in this case... cross join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cross join to get all combinations, and `LEFT JOIN` the tables to that;

```
SELECT x.sid, table1.date, table1.status, x.date bdate, table2.status bstatus
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT table1.sid, table2.date
      FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2) x
LEFT JOIN table1 ON x.sid=table1.sid AND x.date = table1.date
LEFT JOIN table2 ON x.date=table2.date
ORDER BY bdate, sid
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8699/1).

Comment: Perfectly working. Thanks and query is                                                              SELECT x.sid, studentdemo.date, studentdemo.status, x.date bdate, spdemo.status bstatus
FROM (

SELECT DISTINCT studentdemo.sid, spdemo.date
FROM studentdemo
CROSS JOIN spdemo
)x
LEFT JOIN studentdemo ON x.sid = studentdemo.sid
AND x.date = studentdemo.date
LEFT JOIN spdemo ON x.date = spdemo.date
ORDER BY bdate, sid

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using FULL OUTER JOIN.

But currently MySQL doesn't support this type of JOIN. Some time ago I've wrote [a post](http://plutov.by/post/mysql_full_outer_join) about FULL OUTER JOIN trick in MySQL.

Comment: i tried that too but answer is the same                                              SELECT * FROM `studentdemo` left join spdemo on spdemo.date=studentdemo.date
where spdemo.date between "2013-12-28" and "2013-12-30" 
union
SELECT * FROM `studentdemo` right join spdemo on spdemo.date=studentdemo.date
where spdemo.date between "2013-12-28" and "2013-12-30"

Comment: I think a left join would do the job but there is also the issue of no SID being present for the date with the 29th