# Join three tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables

Table 1

```
 student_id |   id  |   status
--------------------------------

10  |   100 |   1
11  |   100 |   1
12  |   100 |   1
13  |   100 |   1
10  |   200 |   1
11  |   200 |   1
12  |   200 |   1
13  |   200 |   1
```

Table 2

```
date    |   status
------------------------    
2013-12-28  |   cd
2013-12-29  |   wd
2013-12-30  |   cd
```

Table 3

```
date    |   id
------------------------    
2013-12-28  |   100
2013-12-30  |   200
```

i need a  null values for all the students dated 2013-12-29

Example:

sid |   date        |   status    | date        |   status
    -------------------------------------------------------

```
10  |   2013-12-28  |   1     | 2013-12-28  |   cd
11  |   2013-12-28  |   1     | 2013-12-28  |   cd
12  |   2013-12-28  |   1     | 2013-12-28  |   cd
13  |   2013-12-28  |   1     | 2013-12-28  |   cd
10  |   null        |   null  | 2013-12-29  |   wd
11  |   null        |   null  | 2013-12-29  |   wd
12  |   null        |   null  | 2013-12-29  |   wd
13  |   null        |   null  | 2013-12-29  |   wd
10  |   2013-12-30  |   1     | 2013-12-30  |   cd
11  |   2013-12-30  |   1     | 2013-12-30  |   cd
12  |   2013-12-30  |   1     | 2013-12-30  |   cd
13  |   2013-12-30  |   1     | 2013-12-30  |   cd
```

I tried with 
[Join two tables in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840581/join-two-tables-in-mysql)

And i used the following query

```
SELECT distinct x.student_id, table1.status, x.date bdate, table2.status bstatus 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT table1.student_id, table2.date 
     FROM table1 
          CROSS JOIN table2) x
          LEFT JOIN table1 ON x.sid=table1.sid 
          left join table3 on table1.id=table3.id and x.date=table3.date 
          LEFT JOIN table2 ON x.date=table2.date ORDER BY bdate, student_id
```

but i did'nt get the null values for 3rd column status.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Am not getting null values for my query                                   SELECT distinct x.student_id, table1.status, 
       x.date bdate, table2.status bstatus
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT table1.student_id, table2.date
      FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2) x
LEFT JOIN table1 
  ON x.sid=table1.sid
left join table3
on table1.id=table3.id
and x.date=table3.date
LEFT JOIN table2
  ON x.date=table2.date
ORDER BY bdate, student_id

Comment: How is adding that in a comment going to help anyone?  Add it to your question.

Comment: @Madusudhanan: do you understand the query you've used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_id,t3.date,IF(t3.date IS NULL, NULL,t1.status) as status,t2.date as date2,t2.status as status2
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 USING(date)
JOIN table1 t1 ON (t1.id = t3.id OR t3.id IS NULL)
ORDER BY date2,student_id
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1ce1/8/0)

Comment: Its working.Please elaborate on how this query works

Comment: well first you want to keep all the dates in table2, so you left join it with table3, to get 3 rows, one with null values for t3.  Then you join this with table1 where matching id or t3.id is null and so you'll get multiple matching ids and multiple null rows but then the Distinct will get rid of the second set of null rows.  You can try it without the distinct and see.